# Families of Sets and Partitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

I have a few questions that I've done and I don't have the solutions for them so I was wondering if anyone might be able to verify my answers and let me know if there are any mistakes! Thanks a lot!

1. Let V = {a,b,c,d} (where a,b,c,d are all distinct) and let A = {a,b}. I need to calculate the following:

(a) {X ⊆ V : A ⊥ X} (where ⊥ means A and X are disjoint)
Attempt at solution: { ∅, {c}, {d}, {c,d}}

(b) {X ⊆ V : V ⊆ X}
Attempt at solution: {{a,b,c,d}}

(c) {X ⊆ V : X ⊥ V}
Attempt at solution: ∅

(d) {X ⊆ V : |X| = 1}
Attempt at solution: { {a}, {b}, {c}, {d} }

(e) {X ⊆ V : |X| < 2}
Attempt at solution: { ∅, {a}, {b}, {c}, {d} }

(f) {X ⊆ V : |X - A| > |X ∩ A|} 
Attempt at solution: { {c}, {d}, {c,d}, {c,d,a}, {c,d,b} }

2. (a) If Pow(X) || Pow(Y), then X || Y. (where '||' means the sets are incomparable, meaning that neither set is a subset of the other and Pow(X) is the Power set of the set X)
   Attempt at solution: True

(b) Each non-empty subset of a non-empty set X is a member of some partition of X.
Attempt at solution: True

(c) If X is non-empty, X ⊆ Y and {V,W} partitions Y, then {V ∩ X, W ∩ X} partitions X.
Attempt at solution: False

Comment: 1a-e are correct.  I skip 1f.  For 2, give real answers;   present a proof or counterexample for each part.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Oh sorry. For 2, I was only asked to determine whether they were true or false. I can try and work out proofs/counterexamples if need be!